# Addressing Views rows separately in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, view, block, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 I have created a block using Views which displays some pictures. I want to take these pictures and add some code to make them slideshow. So I created a file named block--views-block--my-view-name-block-1.html.twig containing the following:

```
{{ content }}
```

which of course displays the three images. My question is, how can I address separately each image? For example I would like to achieve something like this:

```
{% for item in content %} 
 {{ field_image.item }} 
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for item in content %} 
 {{ content.field_image.item }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Or what can I write in twig to simply display one specific image? For example sth like {{ content.field_image.1 }} ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to use a view in `/templates/views`to get this to work. It's a little tricky because Twig debugging doesn't currently (as of 8.6) suggest templates at this level.

For example, if your is an unformatted list view with the machine name `my_custom_view` and you were trying to work with it at the block level `block--views-block--my-custom-view-block.html.twig` you'd rename the `view-view-unformatted.html.twig` template to `view-view--unformatted--my-custom-view.html.twig`. Which view template you use depends on which type of view you're working with (HTML list, unformatted list, table, etc.). This will allow you to iterate at the row level.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for sure but you can just debug:

```
{{ dump(content|keys) }}
```

The command above lists the array keys of "content". I usually do this because it's faster than dumping the whole content variable.

Then you'll see what's exactly in that variable and how you can access the stuff you need.

Note: for debugging in twig you need to enable it first in the services.yml (drupal/sites/default) like this:

```
debug: true
```

Also useful: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel
With *kint* you get a fancier var_dump basically.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but if you want to print only one item you can set number of items to display to "1" in view UI.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment on the above answer by @crash-springfield as I'm missing rep.
This nearly solved it for me, but I had to use the following pattern as the one using the type (as `unformatted` above, `grid` in my case) did not work out. (If at all, it should be `views-view-grid*` without the double dash)

`views-view--<view-name-goes-here>.html.twig`

After that (and a cache rebuild) the template was used and the file name suggestions in the twig debug output also became available (and did not show any other options but the basic `views-view.html.twig`)

The missing file name suggestion seems to be the following bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2118743